# Test if a string contain a combination of a known string and unknown number in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, find

If I have a string for example `line= "hello world 2"` and the number `2` can be any number so line could be `"hello world 4"` is there a way to test that using in operand, I am thinking of something like that

```
if "world %n" in line
```

but that is not correct syntax

Comment: can you use a regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

if re.search("world \d", line):
   ...
```

This uses a quick, simple [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to check the line contains the word 'world' followed by a space followed by any number.

Comment: To be precise, it matches any *single digit* number. To match 1-to-many digit numbers (if required), OP should use `"world \d+"`.

Comment: That worked but it should be re.search not re.match as world is at the end of the string

Comment: @James, I think `re.match(".*world \d.*", line):` is better. (ignoring preceding and following characters before and after `world \d` pattern.

Comment: user5324426 You're right, re.search fits better here - and I think it's cleaner than the .* solution @Chan Kim gave